How to invoke /me/sessions API for tenant user in WSO2 IS?
In the WSO2 Identity server v6.0.0 I've created a tenant and added a user in this tenant.
When i call /api/users/v1/me/sessions and /t/{tenant.domain}/api/users/v1/me/sessions enpoints with this user's access token I get 401 error. Documentation says these are correct URLs. What is the correct way for user to get one's sessions?
For users from super tenant domain both enpoints work well.

Seems the issue is with the used Authorization header value.
If you are using basic authentication for request authorization, check whether you input the username with qualifying the tenant domain?
Check the following sample where user alex in abc.com tenant invokes the API:

Sample curl:
curl --location 'https://localhost:9443/t/abc.com/api/users/v1/me/sessions' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWxleEBhYmMuY29tOmFsZXgxMjM='

YWxleEBhYmMuY29tOmFsZXgxMjM= is base64 decoded value of alex@abc.com:alex123 which is <username>@<tenant domain>:<password>.

I use Bearer token, as this is logical for a frontend application. Does this API allow such a type of authorization?
Cannot find this information in the 6.0.0 documentation.  While the 7.0.0 documentation says: Authorizations: OAuth2 BasicAuth

Oh! Bearer token authorization is supported. It works in our application but without using tenants. The problem is with tenant user accounts.  Looks like another bug.
